# Upgrade from MVC3 rc2 to RTM

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

The release notes cover the MVC2 -> MVC3 path. What about RC2 -> RTM? I installed the RTM via Web Platform Installer but looking to the path that System.Web.Mvc reference in my existing project (C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll) has a date stamp of 1/4/11 so that can't be right.

If i use WPI to install RTM, shouldn't i expect it to have upgraded the RC? Are special steps required in instances where the RC had been installed?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything to upgrade. The RC2 projects are compatible with RTM. And the file date on disk is probably just the date that you installed Mvc, not he version of the mvc dll

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a question in there.

If you installed a newer version of MVC3 on your machine, you'll need to add a new reference to it in your project. Otherwise, your project will stay on the version of the assembly it currently references to avoid breaking changes.

If you find yourself with a lot of problems keeping your assemblies in an up to date reference, check out Microsoft's NuGet project.

Comment: Yes, ones that weren't there before you posted. Look at the edit date.